# Google+ Sign-In Java PhotoHunt Sample doesn't show Google+ Sign-In Button

Tags: java, google-app-engine, angularjs, google-plus

I'm new to Google+ Sign-In and trying to build an application that implement this feature.

So I look up the sample tutorial on https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/java and try to follow it. However, when I deploy this app to App Engine or run it on my localhost:8888, the Google+ Sign-In button doesn't show up. I cannot pretty do anything with the app.

Did any of you run into this problem? I attached a screenshot on what I see when I deploy this app.

[image: screenshot]

The "Invite your friends" button doesn't work either.
I notice that in the index.html, inside  tag, it doesn't have "ng-app" attribute like how other angularjs app has. I'm new to angularjs as well so I don't know if this is the problem. It seems like the angularjs methods didn't get called or something.

Any suggestions will help!

Answer (score 1):

For Angular JS, it can be helpful to install [the Angular JS batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). As far as the sign-in button not rendering goes, that could be caused by a large number of things.

A few things you should try out:

- You could try disconnecting the app from https://plus.google.com/apps and then signing in again
- Check that your authorized origins in [the Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) are correct. Note that http vs https makes a difference.  This can be particularly easy to miss when you are switching from running on AppEngine because it easily supports both.
- Open up the javascript console in your browser and see if you're getting any errors, this might lead you to a solution.
- Watch the network traffic from the Network section of the [Chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), this also might lead to more information about where things are failing
- Verify that all of the scripts are loading by viewing your page source and checking the links in your sources, most notably client|plus.js.
- Verify that the Google client is working properly, you can do this from the console by typing:

  ```
  gapi.client.load('plus','v1');
  ```

If none of these resolutions helps or gets you going in the right direction, you might want to consider re-downloading the sample because something could have happened to your PhotoHunt folder.

Also, which browser are you trying this on?

Comment: I ran it on Chrome and Firefox. I still don't know what's the problem is but somehow it doesn't work on both. On Firefox, the whole page does not even render. On Chrome, the Sign-In button doesn't render.

The solution is to open the site on Chrome Incognito Mode... I guess  my Chrome browser has problem somewhere.

Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: You could try disconnecting and reconnecting the app from https://plus.google.com/apps

Comment: i found the problem... it's because of the "Disconnect" Extension that i have on Chrome...

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I don't use that extension but am experiencing similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/java#google_sign-in_button):

> Visitors **who are not signed in** see the Google+ Sign-In button in the top-right of the page.

Are you signed in with your google account?

Here's the HTML:

```
<span id="signin" ng-show="immediateFailed">
    <span id="myGsignin"></span>
</span>
```

I don't know `Angular.js` either, but I'm guessing the `ng-show` means display the element if `immediateFailed`. Immediate refers to the immediate signin, which is what google does if you're already logged into your google account. If you aren't signed in, and it still isn't displaying, have a look at the `controllers.js` file and see why $scope.immediateFailed would be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the exact solution but it works on my case.

In the code below,

```
<span id="signin" ng-show="immediateFailed">
    <span id="myGsignin"></span>
</span>
```

when i removed `ng-show="immediateFailed"` part, it actually works. I don't know why but i think ng-show tag can not recognized so preventing the rendering of google signin button. when it is removed, button rendering is successful.